# Generate Random No repeating Unique Number

Tags: vba, excel, random

I need to extract a random set of data from a given dump. I have prepared the data and it is working fine.

I have used the rnd() function for picking data in a random manner but sometimes it gives the same output.

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Output").range("D7").Value - 1
    lowest = 1
    highest = Worksheets("Output").range("T5")
    Randomize
    generateno = Int((highest - lowest + 1) * Rnd() + lowest)
    Gen = generateno
    Sheets("Workings").Select
    range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(Gen, 0).Select
    range(Selection, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

Comment: Go here and check out the UniqueRandomLongs function: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/randomnumbers.aspx

Comment: Hi, I have already gone through that. Even I know how to generate no repeating unique number, but this method is not working in my above stated code. Please help me, If you want I can upload the complete sets of code here.

Comment: Assuming your random numbers are unique and you get the same values,  then your data is not unique.

Comment: My data is unique, The random number which are generating is not unique...

Comment: Is it possible, that the random numbers are not defined to generate in a range of cells that's the reason the random numbers are not unique?

Comment: Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: I believe you figured out that you are not using "UniqueRandomLongs". generateno = Int((highest - lowest + 1) * Rnd() + lowest) will give you non-unique random numbers. To be unique, you have to keep track and generate a different number if it has generated previously.

Comment: OP: I just revisit my old comment.  Is this still a problem?

Comment: @Akram  "If you want I can upload the complete sets of code here" <--- please do.. no problem if it helps to clarify the Q..